# WP7: Why does Visual Studio automatically check out WMAppManifest.xml?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, build, checkout, sourcegear-vault

I'm working on a WP7 project and noticed that VS constantly checks out WMAppManifest.xml.  As far as I can tell this happens regardless of what type of code change I make.  Is it possible to prevent this behavior or is it necessary?

Comment: Which Source Control are you using ?

Comment: We are using TFS and do not see this behavior. I hope the file is in the properties folder of the project not the one within bin/debug or release. Just to confirm.

Comment: Correct, it's in the properties folder.  That's strange, I wonder if its related to Vault.

Comment: Yep.. Hopefully someone else should be able to verify it is not checking out WMAppManifest.xml like I see.

Comment: We have Mango Tools beta 2, VS2010SP1, TFS2010 and constantly checking out WMAppManifest.xml while doing a build. File does not get changed - just checked out. I have no idea why this is happening. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed with the latest Mango tools released with the 7712 build.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing here, the file is checked out every time I build a project and it is not modified. The file is always the same as before. I am using TFS. Looks like a bug.